# Getting a forward vector from rotation and position

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have a camera class , It has rotation and position and a method to generate a view matrix from the position and rotation , etch frame the camera sends the view matrix to the renderer. (same for the projection matrix but that's not changing much).

```
class Renderer;
class Camera
{
    Renderer& m_renderer;
    glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix();
public:
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    float Fov;

    Camera(Renderer& renderer,float Fov, int width , int height);
    void MoveCamera(glm::vec3 direction);
    void RotateCamera(glm::vec3 direction);
    void Update();
};
```

what I want to do is to call "MoveCamera" :

```
void Camera::MoveCamera(glm::vec3 direction)
{
    this->position += direction;
}
```

with the `forwardDirection*deltaTime*speed` 
from my main loop. my problem is creating a forward direction vector from my rotation and position. 
rotation is a vector3 with degrees that are used to create a view matrix like this :

```
glm::mat4 Camera::GetViewMatrix()
{
    glm::mat4 matRoll = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 matPitch = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 matYaw = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    matRoll = glm::rotate(matRoll,glm::radians(rotation.z), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    matPitch = glm::rotate(matPitch, glm::radians(rotation.x), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    matYaw = glm::rotate(matYaw, glm::radians(rotation.y), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 rotate = matRoll * matPitch * matYaw;
    glm::mat4 translate = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    translate = glm::translate(translate ,-position);
    return   rotate*translate ;
}
```

So how should I go about making a forward vector out of my position and rotation in this case ?

Comment: I really advice against using Euler angles for this use case. They have a bunch of disadvantages and negligible benefits in this case. Anyway, the forward direction is usually the third row of the view matrix (or its negative).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extract it from your camera view matrix.

Once you have your camera transformation matrix in world space, you can [invert it to get the view matrix](https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-the-view-matrix/)

You are using glm which [uses column-major matrices](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/manual.md#-418-glm_gtc_type_ptr) so you can just grab the second column of the inverted matrix and normalise it to get a direction.

```
const mat4 inverted = glm::inverse(transformationMatrix);
const vec3 forward = normalize(glm::vec3(inverted[2]));
```

Comment: Ok this works but you have to flip the z axis or flip both the y and the x , 
like this 
vec3 forward = normalize(glm::vec3(camera.GetViewMatrix()[2]))*vec3(1 , 1 ,-1);

Comment: how would you go about getting the "left" with this method ? (x axis)

Comment: If you follow the first link I posted you can see it's there already in the matrix. Look at the section called convention.

Comment: Additonally, there are glm convenience functions for this: `side = vec3(row(getViewMatrix(), 0))`